# Why the time complexity of AVL tree in all best , worst and average is logn?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity

`Merge sort`, `insertion sort` and `heap sort`, all have different time complexity of their best worst and average case. I have an idea that they somehow their average and best case nearly give same value but worst case are totally different. However, in case of `AVL tree`,  why they all three cases are same for it ?

Comment: Average, best and worst cases of which operations? The best case of membership testing is O(1), when the element you're testing is at the root node.

Comment: Actually, traditional merge sort is O(n log n) in all cases.